# Subplots not plotting in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm not sure why this is happening when I try to make a 2x2 subplot of 4 maps (images) given my code here. I feel like I'm misunderstanding something.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img1=plt.imread('0507_1994_better_map.png')
img3=plt.imread('0507_2015_better_map.png')
img2=plt.imread('0810_1994_better_map.png')
img4=plt.imread('0810_2015_better_map.png')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img1)
plt.subplot(221)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img2)
plt.subplot(222)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img3)
plt.subplot(223)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img4)
plt.subplot(224)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain what is going wrong, what you were expecting, show us the resulting figure, et cetera. *"why this is happening"* is quite cryptic.

Comment: The problem description is really bad. I might have a guess what you mean: You are missing the first plot? In that case the reason would be that you first show the image and then create the subplot. You would need to reverse that order.

Comment: As mentioned above you can try to describe the problem more clearly. I noticed you are calling `plt.subplot` after `plt.imshow`, you have to call it before.

Answer (score -1):

You should specify **before** you plot something, where it should be plotted:

```
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(221) # this comes first
plt.imshow(img1) # this comes second
plt.axis('off')
...
```